# One ad through different Layouts - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I tried Google this issue and was searched over an hour on Stackoverflow, but I didn't find a solution.

I saw in a few Applications an ad running through different Layouts. I want to implement that in mine app, but I don't know how?

Mine current model is The one which loads new ad every time user change a Layouts. I want the solution which will keep running a same ad even after user change the Layouts. And ad will change after a period of time (60 sec) which I will set in adMob dashboard.

I want to do that because of mine bad statistics on adMob. I think that that's because my RPM attribute : RPM = $0.07  l
PLease, anyone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you build the adview dynamically, you can set a global reference to it after you create it, and then just add it to each View you load up

Comment: Hi Cruceo, I have defined AdView in my .xml files, And every time my app changes xml file I get a new ad. It seems that you suggested a solution thats promising, but can you be more precise? Thanks in advance..

Comment: If I just add AdView to active Layout, than Ad wont show up at all. Thats why I placed it in .xml.

Comment: If you put the ad in XML, it's supposed to refresh every time you change the view. But if you create the add dynamically and then add it to the Views after you create them, as long as you're not re-instantiating the adview, it should persist through the view change

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I haven't worked with AdMob yet, but my general tactic would be the following:

```
// Before starting new activity
View adView = findViewById(R.id.my_add_view); // get ad view
StaticHelperClass.adView = adView; // Set your view to some kind of static helper class
currentActivityLayout.remove(adView);
startActivity(...); // Call new activity
```

In the new activity, add the saved view to the new layout (you should have a container at the correct position where you may add your view).

---

Edit: I just made a quick test with a button, and it worked.